# Changing the axis ticks of a LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting

According to the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html)

> `LogLogPlot` effectively generates a curve in which `Log[f]` is plotted
>   against `Log[x]`, but with tick marks indicating the original values of
>   `f` and `x`.

So for, say,

```
f1[t_] := 1.71*^-10 + 1.08*^-11 t^0.22

f2[t_] := 1.62*^-10 + 1.82*^-11 t^0.18
```

it will produce

```
LogLogPlot[{f1[t], f2[t]}, {t, 0.001, 10000}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I want the ticks of the axis to have the logarithmic values.

I can achieve this as follows

```
modf1[x_] = Log[10, f1[t] /. (a_ + b_ t_^o_) -> a + b 10^(o x)];
modf2[x_] = Log[10, f2[t] /. (a_ + b_ t_^o_) -> a + b 10^(o x)];

Plot[{modf1[x], modf2[x]}, {x, -3, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

But I think there must be an option of LogLogPlot that I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "trick" `Plot` into doing what you want directly, more or less along the lines of what you showed yourself:

```
Plot[
  Log[10, #[10^x]] & /@ {f1, f2}, {x, -4, 4}, 
  Evaluated -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This approach seems more readable to me, and it doesn't require you to generate your own `FrameTicks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am surprized that there is not a single option of `LogLogPlot` for doing this.

Comment: @dimitris In my opinion, your result requires plotting a different function altogether, whereas `LogLogPlot` and similar functions specialize on producing plots of the given function on logarithmic scales. In other words, you want to plot *the logarithm of a function* on a *linear* scale; `LogLogPlot` plots the *function value itself* on a *logarithmic* scale.

Comment: I see your point. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

`FrameTicks` can be used. Assuming you wish equally spaced ticks and only on bottom and left frame components:

```
LogLogPlot[{f1[t], f2[t]}, {t, 0.001, 10000}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{10^j, NumberForm[j, 3]}, {j, Log10[f1[0.001]],
       Log10[f1[10000]], (-Log10[f1[0.001]] + Log10[f1[10000]])/5}], 
    None}, {{#, Log10@#} & /@ PowerRange[0.001, 10000, 100], None}}]
```

You could change divisions to suit.

[image]